# numeric and double errors

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I want to make a mean matrix, whose first row is mean value of columns of df1 who have value i on their clster column, and whose 2nd row is mean value of columns of df2 who have value i on their clster column. I ran code below:

```
for (i in 1:k) {
    df.1[[i]] <- assign(paste0("df1.clstr",i), df1[df1$clster==i,])
    df.2[[i]] <- assign(paste0("df2.clstr",i), df2[df2$clster==i,])
    Mean.list[[i]]<- matrix(colSums(df.1[[i]])/nrow(df.1[[i]]),colSums(df.2[[i]])/nrow(df.2[[i]])),nrow = 2, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

I get error :

> Error in colSums(dth[dth$clster == i, ]) : 'x' must be numeric

when I use as.numeric, I get:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) :    'list'
> object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

What is my mistake here?

Comment: I think these errors are quite informative. You can only take the colSums if your data frame is numeric - the error is telling you that your dataframe contains non numeric values. You must find and remove these values rather than just running ``as.numeric``

Comment: Also, please provide a reprocuible example of your data so that others can help more easily. Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this with `Map`.  Based on the code showed, we could `split` the 'df1', 'df2' by 'cluster', into a `list` of datasets.  Use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements, get the `colMeans` of each element of the `list` and `rbind` together

```
Mean.list <- Map(function(dat1, dat2) 
       rbind(colMeans(dat1),
       colMeans(dat2)),
       split(df1, df1$cluster), split(df2, df2$cluster))
```

Comment: Although I solved my problem in another way, your suggestion is very neat. I would consider this Map() for later uses.